# How many ways can I permute the letters in the word 'ACCOUCHEUSES' with special property?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can I permute the letters in the word 'ACCOUCHEUSES' knowing that the C letters must always be consecutive. I thought the answer was $\frac{10!}{2!2!2!} = 453600$, but it seems my answer is not good. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

All you have to do is pretend that the 3 C's are **glued together** into one unit.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I have done. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Ulice I was careless in not noticing that your analysis is identical to mine.  As far as I can see you **are not wrong**.  What leads you to believe that you are wrong?

Comment: The solution paper

Comment: @Ulice Exactly what does the solution paper read!

Comment: @Ulice Agreed.  You need to share what you think the solution paper reads.  Either the question was written wrong by original author, question was copied incorrectly, solution paper was wrong, or solution is actually correct but merely written in a different way.  If you share the supposedly correct intended solution, it may become clearer which of these it is.  As it currently stands, your answer is correct given the way the question is currently phrased in your post.